# Cordova Resources not created in NetBeans: "Create Cordova Resources and rename site root to 'www'?"

Tags: netbeans, cordova

I'm using **NetBeans 7.4** for **Cordova/Phonegap** development and started a project using the built-in Cordova Application template.

Running the project in the browser (or mobile device browser) works just fine, but every time I choose **Android or iOS**, I get the following dialog:

> **Create Cordova Resources and rename site root to 'www'?**

It then re-creates the project, although it already exists.

I tried clicking on `Create Cordova Resources` in the `Project Properties`, but it keeps saying:

> **Cordova Resources not created.**

[image]

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem here, running NetBeans 7.4 on Windows. It looks like a bug. If you change the cordova/config settings dorung "create project wizard", those are ignored. The config.xml file contains the default values, like `com.coolappz.projectname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly was a bug in NetBeans 7.4.

Fortunately it got **fixed in Netbeans 8.0**.
The new release resolved various issues and provides better compatibility with Cordova (see [NetBeans 8.0 Release Notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/relnotes.html)).

Therefore, download [NetBeans 8.0](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) or greater and you're good to go.

Comment: Not created in version 8.1 on macintosh.

Comment: I get this problem in Netbeans 13

Answer (score 0):

I believe Cordova requires to have all resources (html, JS, CSS, images etc.) in folder called "www" (see [Cordova documentation here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)) and default site root in HTML5 project in NetBeans is called public_html. So if your project's site root has different name, IDE asks you if it can rename it (or perhaps more specifically creates it, move there content of public_html and then remove the empty folder)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ladar. Actually, the resources are already in the www folder and changing the root to public_html had no effect either. NetBeans created the structure itself and when I run it on other platforms than iOS, it works totally fine. There's just this thing with iOS selected...